# Does the function with the αth-weak partial derivative has the βth-weak partial derivative with β≤α?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

The definition of weak derivative in the book *Partial Differential Equations* by Evans is stated as follows:

> Suppose $u,v \in L_{loc}^1(U)$, and $\alpha$ is a multiindex. We say that $v$ is the $\alpha$th-weak partial derivative of $u$, written
>   \begin{equation*}
> D^\alpha u=v,
> \end{equation*}
>   provided
>   \begin{equation*}
> \int_U u D^\alpha \phi d x=(-1)^{|\alpha|} \int_U v \phi d x
> \end{equation*}
>   for all test functions $\phi \in C_c^\infty(U)$.

I have tried to prove that $u$ has the $\beta$th-weak partial derivative for any $\beta \leq \alpha$ if it has the $\alpha$th-weak partial derivative but failed. The reason why I tried to do this is that the text followed in this book seems to assume it holds, though not that obvious for me at the first glance.

PS: Suppose $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$, $\beta=(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n)$ are multiindices. By $\beta \leq \alpha$ we mean $\beta_i \leq \alpha_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: It is not true. Consider functions $u(x,y)$ which are independent of $x$. Then $u_{xy}=0$. But this does not tell you anything about the regularity of $u_y$.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Thank you very much!

Comment: There seems to be some misunderstanding here—we are not talking about regularity in the classical sense.   $u$, as a locally integrable function, is a  distribution and so has (distributional) derivatives of all orders.  The point of the given definition is not to specify when a derivative exists but when this derivative is not just a distribution but even a (specific) locally integrable function, namely $v$.  If $u_{xy}=0$, then $u$ is a sum $u_1(x)+u_2(y)$ (under suitable conditions on the domain) where the two summands are  distributions of a single variable..

Comment: @user131781: And it is possible that $u_2$ is a locally integrable function, but $u_2'$ is not.

Comment: Of course (plus 5).